# MS Access: Input mask not accepting input

Tags: ms-access, validation

I'm trying to create a mask like this: `>L 000 LL`. It should allow a letter, three digits and two more letters. But when I enter something like this - `A 345 BK` - in the "Try it" field of the wizard it says that this input isn't valid, although if I try to enter a really invalid input it beeps and doesn't enter a character. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it is just a bug in the "Try it" field in the Input mask creation wizard. Just skip the check there and try it on a real input.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can have spaces in an input mask.

Comment: I've just tried to replace them with `-` (which is certainly allowed because it's used in preset masks) with the same result. No, spaces are allowed I think.

Comment: It seems that this is just a bug of the "Try it" field... Elsewhere it works.